# D3 force fundamentals?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm struggling to understand the impact of `alphaDecay` and `velocityDecay` and I wouldn't be comfortable trying to explain the concept of `alpha` and `strength` in the context of D3. From my experience level, the [source of the force module](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/) is too *short-and-sweet* and I did not find yet a "D3.force for Dummies" to put me up to speed.

From my tests, I've never associated any significant graph behavior change with different `alphaDecay` values and I've only seen the impact of `velocityDecay` at extreme setting (near 0 or 1). `link.strength()` is also still a mystery.

I'm also really never really sure of when or why I should call `simulation.restart()`.

This all leads to me not being able to have a strategy to come up with a satisfying graph. I feel like I'm always on the edge of a graph that's to explosive or just inert.

I've toyed with [this interesting tool](https://bl.ocks.org/steveharoz/8c3e2524079a8c440df60c1ab72b5d03) and read most of [this](http://www.puzzlr.org/force-graphs-with-d3/), but it doesn't really go around `alpha`,`link.strength`, and other things I've mentioned.

How do you understand these values and how do you configure them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So specifically what they do is documented on the [tick](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_tick) documentation. It says this:

> Increments the current alpha by (alphaTarget - alpha) × alphaDecay; then invokes each registered force, passing the new alpha; then decrements each node’s velocity by velocity × velocityDecay; lastly increments each node’s position by velocity.

I would describe them in this way:

### Alpha

`alpha` I think of as the temperature of the system, which decays over a period of time which I'll use to explain. When the temperature hits 0 (`alphaTarget`) it automatically stops everything from moving, because it assumes there's no energy left. So the simulation stops.

The duration that the system has energy depends on 3 things, the current `alpha`, the `alphaTarget` which is when we should stop and `alphaDecay` which is the speed at which we lose heat from the system. The larger this is, the quicker the force will come to a stop.

### Velocity

Velocity is the speed of the individual items within the force. So after each tick we get an update and the velocity is decreased by the `velocityDecay` ratio. So I treat `velocityDecay` as Friction. The higher the friction, the quicker that individual node will come to a stop.

### Restart

Typically you call `simulation.restart()` off the back of some user action (a node being removed, a link being added etc).

Comment: Really interesting! And how would you describe `link.strength`? Is it a force added on bound nodes in each others direction?

Comment: @VincentDM I would describe link strength as elasticity. Imagine each node connected with some elastic thread, the strength of the link indicates how strong the elastic is, drawing the nodes closer together. On the other hand if the link strength is negative, I picture it like charged particles repelling each other, and the more negative the more repulsion (think putting 2 repelling magnets together).